# Is there any way that my linux system can email me about any files created in home directory?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

Is there any way / script so that whenever the new files gets created inside the /home directory then i get the notification email so that i know if some malicious user has uploaded something on my server

Comment: If you have many users then  your mail box should be made from rubber. You will have to read tons of emails.

Comment: Could you please tell us the situation that you're facing?

Comment: I have all my personal websites , i am not using any mailbox. i only want that when malacious user upload something due to some vulnerability in my site then i should know

Comment: Which method he's using to upload? How do you know it is a malicious script?

Comment: https://github.com/splitbrain/Watcher

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to track such events in Linux is using [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) based utilities, for e. g.:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait
- http://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond

and so on.